# URL redirection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

I have configured SSL in by application example.com and I am also using ELB that acts as the proxy server to the application. Now if someone hits www.example.com, I want it(www.example.com) to be redirected to example.com and also SSL should work.

For that I have done the following in my routes file:

```
constraints(:host => /www.example.org/) do
  match "/(*path)" => redirect {|params, req| "https://example.org/#{params[:path]}"}
end
```

With the above code the redirection is happening properly but the issue is coming for the first time when I hit www.example.org. I am getting SSL issue for www.example.org. If I click advanced then its working. But I don't want this screen to come.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of error happening?

Comment: @error2007s Please find the screen shot attached.

Comment: Did you buy the Ssl certificate for courses.professionalpractise.org or professionalpractise.org? And is your SSL certificate wildcard?